# Can I compile a DLL Project to a Shared Object (.so) File for ARM?

Tags: linux, visual-c++

I have a Microsoft Visual C++ Project with configuration type .dll.
And I want this library to work in my linux system as well,, so how can I compile source code to a .so file???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the C++ for Linux add-in for Visual Studio, which is described in this MSDN blog post: [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/)

Then:

1. Create a new Linux project (`Visual C++ / Cross Platform / Linux / Empty Project`)
2. Change the project settings in the `General` tab so that `Configuration Type` is `Dynamic Library (.so)`
3. Add your source to the project. You can link the source files between projects so you have a common code base.
4. Remove / replace and Windows dependencies
5. Build