# How Can I create a Cmake file from existing visual studio CPP project?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake

I am dealing with relatively big visual studio CPP project (we implemented this project from scratch in windows environment). Now, I have to compile this project in Linux environment. But, I have no idea How I can create a Cmake file from this visual studio project . Is there any straight forward solution?

Thank you

Comment: I have tried automatic solutions but found its best to write the CMakeLists.txt yourself even for a large project. You may want to refactor the layout to be more compatible with CMake when doing so.

Comment: Is CMake essentail to you? If not you can use the Visual Sudio C++ for Linux add-on. You'll have to create a new MSBuild project for the Linux target but, while tedious, is simple and repetetive. You can share the source code. Some more info here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151271/can-i-compile-a-dll-project-to-a-shared-object-so-file-for-arm/51271490#51271490

Answer (score 4):

It would be a great tool if it was possible to convert MSVS project to cmake in Linux environment, but unfortunately I also didn't find such a tool.

However, you can convert VS solution to CMakeLists.txt. You can try [this](https://github.com/algorys/cmakeconverter) or [that](https://github.com/ainvyu/vcxproj2cmake) tools or some others, but then you need to redesign it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CMake Converter](https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html). This tool converts VS solutions to CMake projects. https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html

Unfortunately, this solution is not ideal and could convert your project with some compilation issues, however, it could be a good platform to begin with. I successfully used it to convert a couple of very old MSBuild projects.

The same (not downvoted) answer here, if you'd like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60226700/13292744

Comment: I think the downvote may be because it isn't very clear how to run cmake-converter on Windows.
Here is what I did:-
1. Make sure you have Python installed.

2. From an admin command prompt type:-
 "pip install cmake_converter"
3. To run cmake-converter I used the following on the command prompt:-
 "python c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cmake_converter\main.py -s <solution folder/file>"

Comment: @user2284063 What are you talking about? Installation instructions are on the project page, by the link which I explicitly provided ("Install CMake Converter" section)